# Redefine hbar to work in super- or subscripts

Tags: macros, subscripts, superscripts, kerning

I can redefine the `\hbar` command to use the "h" from the current math font as follows

```
\renewcommand{\hbar}{\raisebox{.5ex}{\rotatebox{15}{--}}\hspace{-0.5em}h}
```

For example in Times New Roman this gives

[image: hbar Times New Roman]

However, this breaks in super- or subscripts:

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve the same result, or is the a way to define `\hbar` differently when it appears as super- or subscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\text`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\renewcommand{\hbar}{%
  \text{\raisebox{.45ex}{\rotatebox{15}{--}}\hspace{-0.5em}$h$}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\hbar+e^{\hbar}+e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]