# How to redefine \hbar and still get the correct unicode character when copying it?

Tags: fonts, macros, fontspec, font-encodings, garamond

I'm using `Garamond Math` on a document, but I don't like the way its `\hbar` looks. I find it too difficult to discern from a regular `h` when on a fraction or on small fonts in general, which could lead to issues when printing the document. Hence, I would like to redefine the `\hbar` glyph to make it more readable. Following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298604/144146), I redefined the `\hbar` command according to this MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\hbar}{%
  \text{\raisebox{.6ex}{\rotatebox{15}{--}}\hspace{-0.55em}\(h\)}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(\hbar \ \hslash\)
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: –ℎ ℏ]

Visually, I really like this result. However, if I copy this output in the pdf and paste it somewhere else I get `–ℎ ℏ`, i.e., the new glyph is actually (as one would expect) `–h`
with some workarounds, rather than truly `ℏ`. Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: There is always brute force: If you have a font editor, edit Garamond Math, and place the character you like instead if its own hbar. TeX does not care. I have done that with ordinary text fonts, where I did not like the shape of `a` or `e`.